# Possible for TSQL query to use a value from a Access Forms?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am working on an Access DB, which have ODBC linked SQL Server table, and I have following script to run TSQL query, as you can see I tried to include a value from Access Forms in the query, but it fails to run. The form is opened and filled with data when I execute the script. I am wondering if this is impossible or there is another way of doing it? I am new to TSQL and SQL server, here is my question. Appreicate if someone can help. Thanks a lot.

```
Function formtest()
Dim qryd As QueryDef
Set qryd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
qryd.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=SQLSERVER;"
qryd.SQL = "UPDATE dbo.table1 SET firstname = [Forms]![testform]![datainput]"
qryd.ReturnsRecords = False
qryd.Execute
End Function
```

Comment: How exactly do you expect the server to read from your local file?  You have to read from the local file and send it to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server doesn't know anything about your forms.  You have to send the data with the query.  Something like this:

```
qryd.SQL = "UPDATE dbo.table1 SET firstname =  '" & [Forms]![testform]![datainput] & "'"
```

One thing you have to be aware of though is that if there are any single quotes in your `datainput` it could invalidate the SQL.  It could also be a security issue.  Either test for single quotes and raise an error, or replace each of them with two.

The best way to do it is to use a parameterized query.  This will absolutely prevent issues SQL injection and also help with performance in many cases.  Unfortunately, I don't believe you can create a paramaterized query for SQL Server using DAO.  You would have to convert to ADO, which is best suited for sending queries to a SQL Engine other than Jet.

To use ADO you might have to add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects by opening the VBA code window and selecting Tools -> References -> and checking the box next to it.  Then your code would look something like this:

```
Dim Conn1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd1 As ADODB.Command
Dim Param1 As ADODB.Parameter

Rem Create and Open Connection Object.
Set Conn1 = New ADODB.Connection
Conn1.ConnectionString = "ODBC;DSN=SQLSERVER;"
Conn1.Open

Rem  Create Command Object.
Set Cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
Cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn1
Cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.table1 SET firstname = ?"

Rem  Create Parameter Object.
Set Param1 = Cmd1.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 25)
Param1.Value = [Forms]![testform]![datainput]
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Param1
Set Param1 = Nothing

Rem  Open Recordset Object.
Call Cmd1.Execute
```

Comment: And this is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: Correct... the security issue I warned about is called "SQL Injection".  The user of this snippet must take precautions to prevent it.

Comment: Why not just adjust your answer and parameterize this? Then it would be an excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Pressler, it works great!! Much appreciate. I searched the sql injection definition, it seems only applies to web application? Will it also happen to Access script? Thanks.

Comment: SQL injection can be an issue in any instance where you are building a query string by concatenating with user entered variables.  It's often very important in web programming because the users are generally over the internet.  In Access projects where the client user needs to have access to connect to the SQL Server directly it may not be as much of an issue because your users are generally employees of your organization, but it can still be exploited.  Best to use parameters... I've added some additional information to my answer.